# Jquery Remove All Clones On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good Morning, 
I am trying to remove all of the cloned `.cloneIndex` boxes except the original on `.send` button click.

Remove Action only removes 1 per click.

```
   $("button.remove").live("click", function(){
    if (Remove == true) {
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
     cloneIndex--;    
    }else {
     $('.quantity').val('');
     $('.width').val('');
     $('.height').val('');
     $('.special-note').val(''); 
    }
    errordisable = true;    
   });
```

Code Demo https://jsfiddle.net/mkf8g728/

Thanks Again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. This will remove all the clonedInput class divs except the first one. By the way, your code will generate clonedInput1 twice FYI. This solution accounts for that bug (feature?).

```
   $("#Submit").live("click", function(){
       $( ".clonedInput:not(:first)" ).each(function(){
           $(this).remove();
       });
   });
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Drakes/mkf8g728/1/

Comment: Code works great, but once the user presses send it removes properly but then the user can click the X and remove the last one now?